# Angular 5 - Import Module into Dynamic Module

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular5, owl-carousel

I am relatively new to Angular 5. I've been trying to create dynamic components with a template retrieved from a service. I have been able to render basic templates with this function:

```
createComponent(): void {
  this.container.clear();
  // create dynamic component using template and item
  const component = Component({template: this.template})(class {});
  const module = NgModule({
    imports: [
      CommonModule
    ],
    declarations: [component],
    entryComponents: [component]
  })(class {});
  // compile module
  this.compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(module)
    .then((factories) => {
      const factory = factories.componentFactories[0];        
      this.componentRef = this.container.createComponent(factory);
      this.componentRef.instance.item = this.item;
      this.componentRef.instance.app = this.app;
    });
}
```

Now that I have simple templates rendering, I am trying to get an Owl Carousel rendering in my template. When I try to import the Angular module `OwlModule` into my dynamic `NgModule`, nothing is rendered and I don't receive any errors in the console.

Here is the code I am using in my template to render the carousel:

```
<owl-carousel *ngIf="trendingItems.length > 0" [items]="trendingItems[0]['Carousel Media']" [carouselClasses]="['owl-theme', 'row', 'sliding']">
  <div *ngFor="let media of trendingItems[0]['Carousel Media']">
    <div *ngIf="media.MediaTypeId == 1000 || media.MediaTypeId == 1001">
      <div layout="column" layout-fill="">
        <div *ngIf="media.MediaTypeId == 1000" class="img-container">
          <img data-src="{{app.mediaPath(media)}}" class="img-responsive" id="image-height">
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="media.MediaTypeId == 1001" class="videoBox">
          <video media="media"></video>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</owl-carousel>
```

This renders just fine when I hard-code it into a non-dynamic template, so I don't believe this is the problem. Also, the template still doesn't render even if the `owl-carousel` directive is not on the page.

Is there something that I am missing? Is there a special way to import custom modules into dynamic modules?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this may be supported by Webpack's Dynamic Import Feature:

https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/